# Stop a For Loop From Repeating in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, for-loop

I'm trying to replace some html code with Javascript when a user searches for an email.  I have it working correctly, but for some reason the error displays around 20+ times, so it will replace the div and say

"user does existuser does existuser does existuser does existuser does existuser does exist"

instead of just putting the error message once.  Any idea how I can fix it?

```
$scope.checkEmail = function 
findUsersMatchingEmail(emailAddress) {
    ref.child('users').orderByChild('email').
        equalTo($scope.emailAddress).once('value', function (snap) {

        var output = '<div>',
            myError = document.querySelectorAll('#d');
        for (var key in arguments[0]) {
            output += (snap.name() + 
                      (snap.val() === null ? ' Does Not' : ' does') + ' exist');
        }
        output += '</div>';

        for (var i = myError.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            myError[i].innerHTML = output;
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Why do you only want the error to display once if multiple users do not exist?

Comment: Is that code inside the link function of a directive? If not, what I would assume, then you're doing it wrong. Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background

Comment: they Only search for one email at a time, so the error displays above the form with either a "this user does exist" or "this user does not exist".  If they want to search for multiple users, they delete what's in the form and search again

Comment: @Yoshi Yes, it's using an ngsubmit directive on the form to trigger the function.

Comment: Ok, then by all means, read to linked question and answer. For you should never manipulate the DOM outside of a directive.

Comment: The problem isn't getting the function to work, it's getting the error message to only display once...

Comment: The problem is that the function should never work, because you can't assume that it will only be called once. Trust me, if you manipulate the dom from anywhere outside a directive, then you're bound to run into problems.

Comment: @Yoshi Hrrm... So what's the best way to notify the user?  By directive do you mean controller?  This page has its own controller, where the function resides.  see http://uakk9bef7e78.alteredorange.koding.io/#/find to see the actual page

Comment: There are multiple things. Maybe add a scope variable `.errors[]` and store errors inside it. Those errors you could clear/add *on-submit*. In your view you'll then use `ng-repeat="error in errors"` and similar. I can add a simple demo as an answer if it would help?

Comment: @Yoshi a demo would definitely help, thanks!

Comment: One last question, is `ref` an injected service or a global? (hoping for the first ;))

Comment: yes it's injected not global

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I wrote in the comments, never manipulate the DOM from anywhere but the link function of a directive. Explaining why is probably out of scope for this answer, and has been answered multiple times here on SO. A very good read is:

- [“Thinking in AngularJS” if I have a jQuery background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)
- and [A Conceptual Introduction to AngularJS](http://paislee.io/a-conceptual-introduction-to-angularjs/)

So to make it short, here's a very simple demo of how you could handle your error messages.

Note that this is by no means the only nor the best way to do it. There's [`ngMessages`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages/directive/ngMessages) or [form validation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms) in general which could be used as well.

```js
(function (app) {
  'use strict';

  app.controller('EmailCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.errors = [];

    $scope.checkEmail = function findUsersMatchingEmail(emailAddress) {
      // clear previous errors
      $scope.errors.length = 0;

      // check email and add errors if needed
      // using your service (ref)
      $scope.errors.push({
        message: 'email not unique ' + (Math.random()) // random is only used to show that the errors actually change
      });
    };
  }]);

})(angular.module('app', []));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<div data-ng-app="app" data-ng-controller="EmailCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="error in errors">{{ error.message }}</li>
  </ul>

  <form data-ng-submit="checkEmail(email)">
    <input data-ng-model="email" placeholder="email">
  </form>
</div>
```

*Side note*: I would normally use the `controller as` syntax, though I did not want to introduce any more new topics.

Comment: Thanks Yoshi!  Got that running like a champ!